# What books do you recommend on mathematics behind cryptography?

Tags: number-theory, statistics, reference-request, cryptography

I am currently reading the Book Understanding Cryptography from Cristof Paar. I am enjoying the book but i don't like to scratch the surface when it comes to cryptography. I would like do dig a little deeper on the mathematics behind it. I read on:

https://www.schneier.com/crypto-gram/archives/1999/1015.html

that cryptography demands an understanding of multiple fields of mathematics, such as:

-Number theory

-Complexity theory

-Algorithms

-Statistics

-Abstract algebra

I have a masters on Telecommunications and Informatics, so i have an understanding of mathematics, calculus, statistics, algebra and complex calculus. I am no pro, but i think i am good. Could you advise me on books i should buy? I would like books that explain theorems and demonstrate those theorems. Do you think i am doing the right thing? Should i read only applied cryptography books, or should go deeper on the subject? I would like to go beyond the basic understanding. I would like to develop algorithms and break other algorithms. If you know books that talk about all these subjects, they are more than welcome.

Thank you

Kind regards

Comment: [Cross-posted on Crypto](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/22609/books-on-cryptography-mathematics)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I would recommend a series of books, specifications, libraries and CAS programs.

**Books**

- A Course in Number Theory and Cryptography, Neal Koblitz (very dense, but an amazing book)
- An Introduction to Mathematical Cryptography, Jeffrey Hoffstein, Jill Pipher, J.H. Silverman (very readable and excellent book, which is more up-to-date)
- An Introduction to Cryptography, Second Edition (Discrete Mathematics and Its Applications), Richard A. Mollin (easier on the math)
- [*Handbook of Applied Cryptography*](http://cacr.uwaterloo.ca/hac/), Alfred J. Menezes, Paul C. van Oorschot and Scott A. Vanstone (note, there is also a variant for Elliptic Curve Cryptography and both are just an excellent way to describe and detail cryptographic algorithms)
- As a side note, these should be supplemented with books on Number Theory, Abstract Algebra, Algebraic Geometry and the like, but there are many excellent posts for such books on MSE

**Specifications**

- NIST [*Digital Signature Standard*](http://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/FIPS/NIST.FIPS.186-4.pdf) - you can see what a real-world specification looks like.
- Many other NIST specifications
- IETF's [*Request For Comments*](http://www.ietf.org/rfc.html) (RFCs)

**Software Libraries**

- [*Libtomcrypt*](https://github.com/libtom/libtomcrypt) and [*Libtommath*](https://github.com/libtom/libtommath)
- [*Crypto ++*](http://www.cryptopp.com/)

**Computer Algebra Systems**

- Mathematica, Maple, ... (not free, professional packages with large integer math)
- SAGE, Pari/Gp, ..., Python (free)
- Here is a [*list of CAS programs*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_computer_algebra_systems), which is very helpful for experimenting with number theory topics and quickly coding things up (enormously helpful)

There are many others, but these are the ones I go back to often.

Answer (score 2):

Understanding Cryptography, A textbook for students and practitioners by Christof Paar, Jan Pelzl. ISBN 978-3-642-04100-6 by Springer publishes. That's the book we are doing in my university and it's really helpful. It has a lot of examples, and it can be understood easily. Give it a try.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).