# Can I take cryptography after doing pure Mathematics $?$

Tags: soft-question

This is not a mathematics problem . May be it's not appropriate to ask this here but I don't know anywhere else to go for advice .

I have taken Pure Mathematics at the university and quite enjoying doing it . Since I was thinking about doing research work after this so I was talking with some of the professors . The ones with specialization in topics of *pure*  said they may not appointing new scholars the next semester. So I talked with another who works in *applications of algebra* i.e. mostly in *cryptography* and *combinatorial graph theory* .

So , my question is , is it possible to do research work in those above after having studied only *abstract* and *linear* algebra and very little of *commutative* algebra $?$ I had this thought because he said those are **applications of algebra** and since we have to do a course-work for $1$ year in the chosen subject.

I  mean I will have to learn a lot of new things any ways for research work , not like my knowledge from the degree courses will suffice at all. So , my not knowing the above two things at all this time , does that make it impossible  to chose **applications of algebra**  as research topics $?$  Not that all depends on my decision , it's his decision  all that matters but should I request him at least $?$

Comment: It really depends on the course, so the best person to ask is the person who will be teaching the course...

Comment: @ThomasAndrews : Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you haven't taken a course in cryptography, have a look at the book [An Introduction to Mathematical Cryptography](http://www.math.brown.edu/~jhs/MathCryptoHome.html) by Hoffstein, Pipher, and Silverman. If you can follow it, you can probably start a study on the subject.

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1121026/589.